# Integrating oracledb in cloudfoundry custom buildpack

Tags: cloud-foundry

Our goal is to integrate our node.js webservice in cloudfoundry. Since we need the oracledb module to access our database, we were forced to creating a custom buildpack (forked from the cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack), which installs the required oracle instantclient.

After downloading and unzipping the instantclient and sdk within the `s.Stager.BuildDir() + '/instantclient-basic'` directory, it seems we have to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable to this very path.

So, within the `/src/nodejs/supply/supply.go` file, we added following lines of code:

```
if err := s.Stager.WriteEnvFile("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", filepath.Join(s.Stager.BuildDir(), "instantclient-basic")); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

However, in the log output when installing this buildpack, where it lists the other variables like `NODE_ENV` or `NODE_HOME` (which are set exactly the same way) my variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is missing. How do I properly export a new env variable?

---- Edit in response to Daniel Mikusa's Answer ---

I tried following the `.profile` including the instantclient files approach:

```
- controllers
- public
- instantclient
| --- libclntsh.so
| ... 
app.js
server.js
package.json
.profile
```

This is how the .profile file looks like:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME/app/instantclient
```

Still, when I create a .zip out of this, and stage a new nodejs buildpack on our cloundfoundry, I get the same error as before:

> ERR Error: NJS-045: cannot load the oracledb add-on binary for Node.js 6.11.2 (linux, 64)
>
> ERR Node.js require() error was:
>
> ERR DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".

Do you see any mistake here?

Comment: If this is a Linux VM and the only Oracle software is Instant Client, then look at using ldconfig as described in the Instant Client installation instructions: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html#ic_x64_inst  This avoids having to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in each shell that is invoking Node.js.

Comment: I have tried writing to the file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf`, however, access is denied and sudo seems not possible either.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to start by referencing the buildpack contract docs here.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/custom.html#contract

You are calling `s.Stager.WriteEnvFile`, which you can see the source for here.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/libbuildpack/blob/e915de2390c8dcc4f3a05dd747c7635454335e26/stager.go#L76

This method is writing an env file.  From the buildpack docs...

> The following directories may be created inside of /tmp/deps/IDX/ to provide dependencies to subsequent buildpacks:
>
> ...
>
> - `/env`: Contains environment vars intended for staging, loaded as FILENAME=FILECONTENTS

So what you've added should create an env file that subsequent buildpacks can use.  Is that what you're intending?

If you want to set env variables at runtime (i.e. when your application runs), then you need to modify this part of the buildpack.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack/blob/master/src/nodejs/supply/supply.go#L586-L593

```
    scriptContents := `export NODE_HOME=%s
export NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV:-production}
export MEMORY_AVAILABLE=$(echo $VCAP_APPLICATION | jq '.limits.mem')
export WEB_MEMORY=${WEB_MEMORY:-512}
export WEB_CONCURRENCY=${WEB_CONCURRENCY:-1}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/instant-client
`

    return s.Stager.WriteProfileD("node.sh", fmt.Sprintf(scriptContents, filepath.Join("$DEPS_DIR", s.Stager.DepsIdx(), "node")))
```

Just make sure that `/path/to/instant-client` is relevant in the runtime container, not in the staging container.  The paths can differ.

---

For what it's worth, I would only suggest forking the buildpack if you have a lot of apps that need this adjustment.  It requires maintenance to keep a buildpack current, and you don't want your fork to fall behind or you can get stuck running old versions of node, or whatever binaries are provided by your buildpack, which may have security vulnerabilities.

If you just have a few applications, you should be able to bundle the instant client with your application files.  To do this, just extract the instant client to a subfolder of your project folder.  Then add a file named `.profile` to the root of your project folder.  Inside that file, add `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME/app/instant-client-folder`.

When you push your app, the `.profile` file will be sourced.  That will append the instant client folder to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, which should make it available to your application.

More details on `.profile` here -> https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/deploy-app.html#profile

Comment: Thanks a lot for your informative answer! Since we basically just have one node.js application that needs the oracledb library, your second approach sounds interesting! It seems I'm still doing something wrong, I have updated my initial post. Do you see any mistake?

Comment: "Because the .profile script executes after the buildpack" --> Isn't it too late to set the variable then, since the installation of node-oracledb will need it to be set already?

Comment: @user66875 What is the oracle library/NPM trying to do with the libraries during staging?  The `.profile` is only a runtime hook so it's not applied when the buildpack runs.  You may be able to work around that by vendoring your dependencies locally.  See here -> https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node/index.html#vendoring.